# DatePickerIOS nothing happen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, datepicker

When i try to use DatePickerIOS with react native nothing happen in my phone ...
my code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text, View, DatePickerIOS} from 'react-native';

export default class DatePicker extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            today: new Date(),
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <DatePickerIOS date={this.state.today} mode="time" onDateChange={(value) => this.setState({today: value})}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

SomeOn know why ?

Comment: So what SHOULD happen? Looking at the code you are just setting state.

Comment: You forget DatePickerIOS normally I should see a picker Date but it did not belong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print selected time in the UI add the following to the `render`

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <DatePickerIOS 
        date={this.state.today} 
        mode="time" 
        onDateChange={(value) => this.setState({today: value})}
      />
      <Text>{this.state.today.toTimeString()}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```